# Self watering planters. Top watering strategies

Tags: houseplants, indoors, watering, ficus

There really isn’t much definitive information on self watering pots.

I’ve planted 3 6ft tall fiddle leaf plants in a Lechuza 43cm pot. The pot instructions say every third watering fill the reservoir by top watering. They say to do this to regulate the mineral build up. [This](https://greeneryunlimited.co/blogs/plant-care/fiddle-leaf-fig-care) article mentions never top watering as it will drown the plant.

Continuing to top water (every third time) sounds sensible to me. The roots above the reservoirs should receive some moisture and surely letting the substrate above the reservoirs become bone dry can’t be good. Is my reasoning correct ?

Top watering is sure to be iffy as when I watered it in the original nursery pot I could pass through six litres and only have one cup drain out. The reservoirs holds six litres. So if I fill the reservoir from the top I’d probably have to put probably 9-12 litres through.

Main question: is top watering really needed ? if I do top water how should I do it ? I live in a flat and the pot does not have a removable inlay so getting it wrong is gonna be a disaster.

[image]

Comment: I suspect what's happening is that by relying on the reservoir you're encouraging/forcing the roots to grow deep. Then, if you top-water once they've grown deep and become accustomed to reservoir-watering, the roots will be somewhat overwhelmed. This is just my beginner gardener attempt at trying understand what that page is saying. I could very well be wrong.